# How to extend a resolved $resource with business logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following scenario

### Service:

```
.factory(
    'itemsApi',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource("/api/items/:id", { id: "@_id" }, {
            'create': { method: 'POST' },
            'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
            'update': { method: 'PUT' }
        });
    })
```

### Router

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/item/:id", {
        templateUrl: "item.tpl.html",
        controller: "ItemController",
        resolve: {
           item: ['$route', 'itemsApi', function ( $route, itemsApi) {
                return itemsApi.get({ id: $route.current.params.id });
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

### Controller

```
.controller('ItemController',['$scope','item', function($scope, item) {
    $scope.item = item;
}
```

So far everything works fine. I have the item in my controller. Now I want to extend `$scope.item` with my Business logic.

### Business Logic

```
function Item() {}

Item.prototype.totalPrice = function() {
   // $scope.item should be here 'this'
   return this.price + this.shipping;
}
```

### The Goal:

Extend `$scope.item` with business logic in Angular Way.

I tried using `angular.extend` but doesn't work. $scope.item does not have the totalPrice function.

for instance: *in controller*

```
$scope.item = angular.extend(item, new Item());
```

### The Question

How I can get elegantly that `$scope.item` contains the methods of the `Item` class?

---

## EDIT

The proposed solution by @ryeballar creates an ugly effect.

Now '$scope.item' wraps the $resource in '$scope.item.item'

So i should change every bindings path in the document.

#### From

```
<span ng-bind="item.price"></span>
```

#### To

```
<span ng-bind="item.item.price"></span>
```

This is not aceptable to me, feels bad practice. then I thought of this solution

#### Item constructor

```
var Item = function Item(item) {
    // mixing
    angular.extend(this, item);
};
```

This solved the last problem but generated new one.

Now `$scope.item` not contain the `$resource` methods. (eg `$scope.item.update()`) due `__proto__` chaged from `Resourse` to `Item`

### Finally

Although `$socpe.item` does not have anymore `update` and `create` methods. `itemApi` can be used instead.

```
if ($scope.item._id) {
    itemsApi.update({ id: $scope.item._id}, $scope.item)
            .$promise.then(function(item) {
                    $scope.item = new Indoor(item);                       
            });
} else {
    itemsApi.create($scope.item)
            .$promise.then(function(item) {
                    $scope.item= new Indoor(item);
             });
}
```

Comment: When you say it did not work, what do you mean? The $scope.item did not have the totalPrice function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a factory service for your `Item` model and inject it in your resolve, and then return the resolved value as an `Item` Object.

**Item Service**

```
.factory('Item', function() {
  var Item = function(item) {
    this.item = item;
  };

  Item.prototype.totalPrice = function() {
    return this.item.price + this.item.shipping;
  };

  return Item;
});
```

**Router**

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/item/:id", {
        templateUrl: "item.tpl.html",
        controller: "ItemController",
        resolve: {
           item: ['$route', 'itemsApi', 'Item', function ( $route, itemsApi, Item) {
                return itemsApi.get({ id: $route.current.params.id })
                  .$promise.then(function(item) {
                    return new Item(item);
                  });
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ItemController', ['$scope', 'item', function($scope, item) {
  $scope.item = item; // this is an Item Object
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
{{item.totalPrice()}}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, simply chain the `$promise` property after the `get()` method invocation.